# Процесс, запущенный под systemd, грузит процессор

Tags: linux, systemd

Есть сервер (Debian stretch, kernel 4.19.0-9-amd64)

Есть кастомная утилита `/opt/some-server/some-service`, есть пользователь и группа `some-service`.

При попытке запустить сервис из-под пользователя всё ок. Сервис крутится, нагрузка на процессор особо не возрастает (смотрю в `htop`, при этом ssh-консоль не лагает)

Определяю сервис в systemd

```
# /etc/systemd/system/some-service.service 
[Unit]
Description=Some service
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=idle
User=some-service
Group=some-service
ExecStart=/opt/some-server/some-service
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Заспускаю службу

```
service some-service start
```

Служба становится доступна извне по нужному порту, как и положено, но грузит процессор на 100%

Пробовал в файле `/etc/systemd/system/some-service.service` закомментировать строки

```
#User=some-service
#Group=some-service
```

В этом случае при запуске сервиса через systemctl процессор грузится так же, как при ручном запуске от юзера, но извне по нужному порту не доступен.

Пробовал менять параметр `Type` на `simple`, добавлять `Restart` (`always` и `on-failure`). Результатов не дало.

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать?

Comment: Я бы взялся за strace

Comment: "При попытке запустить сервис из-под пользователя всё ок." - в чём разница с запуском из под "systemd" ? Ответ простой: 1) Разные права 2) Разные переменные окружения. 

В частности, я бы внимательно посмотрел на $PATH.

Comment: @Sergey сделал `printenv > /home/some-service/some-service/env`, в `/etc/systemd/system/some-service.service` в секции `[Service]` добавил строку `EnvironmentFile=/home/some-service/some-service/env` и раскомментировал `User=some-service` и `Group=some-service`. Далее выполнил `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` и запустил сервис. Правильно я понимаю, что права и переменные окружения теперь должны быть идентичны ручному запуску из-под юзера? Увы, результат не изменился

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Я посмотрел PID в htop при запущенной слубе, сделал `strace -p $PID`, потом остановил службу, запустил команду руками из-под пользователя напрямую, повторил strace с новым PID. Картина в целом одинаковая. Вывод состоит из строчек `nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=15000000}, NULL) = 0`, только число в хаотичной (?) последовательности варьируется между `15000000`, `14000000` и `1000000`.

Comment: @IvanDudarev "Правильно я понимаю" -  я и сам не знаю деталей запуска сервисов. Но я бы поступил наоборот - в скрипт запуска сервиса вставил вывод в файл переменных окружения. А потом бы сравнил с тем, что имеем в терминале.

Comment: @Sergey проверил, параметры идентичные (за исключением `INVOCATION_ID` и `JOURNAL_STREAM`, которые добавляются при старте сервиса. Но они же не могут повлиять на подобное поведение?)

Comment: а журнал работы данного сервиса не смотрели? возможно там есть инфа что происходит: 
journalctl -u some-service -t

Comment: @zersh Смотрел. Там всё идентично выводу в консоль при запуске сервиса вручную

Comment: Попробуй тогда запуск через баш с выводом ошибок в консоль: ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'exec /path-to-some-service 2>&1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема обнаружилась в том, что сервис читал из stdin. Начинал читать после вывода всех логов, что сбивало с толку. Когда сервис был настроен на работу без stdin, проблема прошла. Большое спасибо всем откликнувшимся!